# Printing words that start with "a"(in a string)

Tags: c++, string

I need my program to `print` those words that start with a specified letter.
Let's say that this letter is `"a"`.

I've tried to create an algorithm, but it doesn't work properly since the loop is infinite :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    char slovo = 'a';
    string::size_type k = 0, pos = 0;
    cout << "Enter string" << endl;
    getline(cin,str);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == slovo) 
            while (str[i + 1] != ' ' && i < str.length()) cout << str[i];
        cout << ' ';
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

For example :

I enter: `"another apple has fallen"`
Specified letter is `"a"`
Desired output: `"another apple"`

Comment: I would use `operator>>` to read a `std::string`. This reads a word at a time. Then you can just check the first letter and print if its your selected character. `std::string word; while ( std::cin >> word) { /* STUFF */}`

Comment: You should iterate `i` in the `while loop` !! Moreover, you never output the characters that you found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of this simple example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string t;
    getline(cin,t);

    istringstream iss(t);
    string word;
    while(iss >> word) {
        /* do stuff with word */
        if(word[0] == 'a')
        cout << word << " ";
    }
}
```

[Try online](http://cpp.sh/9tsx)

Now when i enter :

```
another apple has fallen
```

Output is :

```
another apple
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few logical errors in the code:

1. The while loop does not increment `i`, and that is the reason for the infinite loop.
2. You should start with `i = 1` in the for loop to check for the start of the word for the initial first-word condition. And then for other words you check whether there is a space before the first character of the word, that would make sure for the algorithm that it is a word in the sentence.

---

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    char slovo = 'a';
    string::size_type k = 0, pos = 0;
    cout << "Enter string" << endl;
    getline(cin,str);
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((str[i] == slovo && str[i-1] == ' ') || (i == 1 && str[i-1] == slovo)){
            if (i == 1) {
                cout << str[i-1];
            }
            while (str[i] != ' ' && i < str.length()) {
                cout << str[i];
                i = i + 1;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

The output it gives is:

```
Enter string
another apple has fallen 
another
apple
```